# Create, write, read file in proc.c XV6 OS

Tags: c, xv6

I want to create a file in proc.c (kernel mode) and write something to it but the provided system call (open) is for user mode in user.h header and I can't include user.h in proc.c, Is there any other way to do this in proc.c?

Answer (score 1):

Use the code of the 'open' system call found in function sys_open() in sysfile.c, and assign the 'path' and 'omode' variables yourself.

(If you want to avoid code duplications, you can edit sys_open to call another function with the 'path', 'omode' variables, and use that function in your code in proc.c)

Comment: I have seen this (sys_open()), but just as you said I don't know how to use it  and also I can not understand how open() function is related to it... please if it's possible give me a description and an example...

Comment: When you use open(), a system call is made, and the kernel runs sys_open(). To use it you can copy the code of sys_open() to proc.c, and edit it to your needs

Comment: but I think I should do something like open because sys_open() code depends a lot on other functions inside sys_file.c, Do you know how to do such thing?

Comment: You can include sys_file.h (if there is such), or the files containing the methods you need - it is ok because they are all kernel

Comment: So maybe you can include what sys_file.c is including (it is to better find only the needed ones among them)

Answer (score 0):

You should study the kernel file system.
There you will see the relevant kernel functions.

Specifically You need the `create`, `writei`, `iput` functions.
You will also need `begin_trans` and `comnit_trans` (since you are writing).